# Why arrow actions ignore in mac os terminal using ssh?

Tags: macos, ssh, debian, terminal

I use ssh connect to debian using mac os terminal.
So I have this issue if I "press up right down left":

```
$ ^[[A^[[C^[[B^[[D
```

at the same time everything ok in local terminal.

Esc+, Option+ and Ctrl+ doesn't help.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Special keys like arrows are the individual programs' responsibility on Unix-style terminals.

On the Debian host you're using a shell that doesn't support arrow keys – most likely `/bin/sh` or something equally "minimal".

Try starting `bash` or `zsh`. If one of them works, make the setting permanent using `chsh`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set (or change the value of) your `TERM` environment variable. Perhaps your Debian host doesn't recognize what you have it set to. Try changing it to `xterm-256color`, `xterm-color`, `xterm`, `ansi`, or `vt100`, and run `/usr/bin/reset`. E.g:

```
$ TERM=xterm ; export TERM
$ reset
```

You can also try going into the Mac OS Terminal.app's Preferences and changing "Declare terminal as...".

The xterm-256color profile is relatively new and if you have an old version of Linux it might not know about it yet. Similarly, if you had `TERM` set to `linux` or `console`, Terminal.app might not recognize it.